# How to call array of multiple async methods in Angular using Rxjs?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs

I have the `Base Validator` method which has list of `ivalidator`.

```
import { IValidator, ValidatorModel } from "../validation/ivalidator";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

export abstract class BaseValidator implements IValidator {

    private validators = new Array<IValidator>();

    //Validators are pushed to the base validator =>Not implemented yet

    validate(): Observable<ValidatorModel> {

        for (let i = 0; i < this.validators.length; i++) {
            //How do I loop thru all the validator and call its ASYNC method 
            //one by one and break and return when there is an error ???
        }

    }
}
```

Each `validator` method exposes the `validate()` method which returns an observable.

```
export interface IValidator {
    validate(): Observable<ValidatorModel>;
}
```

ValidatorModel is

```
export class ValidatorModel {
    readonly isSuccessful: boolean;
    errors: Array<string>;
}
```

My question is :

How do I loop thru all the validator and call its ASYNC method 
    one by one and break and return when there is an error ???

Answer (score 1):

If you want the your validations to be executed one by one, use the [`merge`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) operator:

```
validate(): Observable<ValidatorModel> {
    let obs = this.validators.map(validator=>validator.validate());
    return Observable.merge(obs);
}
```

If you want your validations to be executed parallel at the same time, use the [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) operator:

```
validate(): Observable<ValidatorModel> {
    let obs = this.validators.map(validator=>validator.validate());
    return Observable.forkJoin(obs);
}
```

As for error handling, both `merge` and `forkJoin` will throw the error whenever they encounter them, and you can handle it at your `subscribe()` handler. If you are doing (pipe) more operations to the `Observable<ValidatorModel>`, then the error will be thrown up the final stack:

```
someValidator.subscribe(
            (results) => {
            },
            (error) => {
                //handle error here
            },
            () => {
                //observable completed
            })
```

If you choose to explicitly handle the error in your base class, then use the `catch` operator:

```
return Observable.forkJoin(obs)
    .catch(error=>{
        console.log('error encountered',error);
        //handle your errors here
        //Return an empty Observable to terminate the stream
        return Observable.empty();
    });
```

Comment: so, how do I "break" when I find that one of the validator has "errored" out?

Comment: I mean I want to handle error based on the isSuccessful flag not on "throwing" exception.

Comment: Also there is compile time error Observable.merge(obs) returns Observable<Observable<ValidationModel>>